# @Transaction - How to commit to another method in same transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I Have a method using @Transactional annotation, and inside this method, i have one that persists one entity, and the next ones uses this persisted entity that is not yet persisted, because the method using @Transactional dont finished.

What is the best approach to do this? I Think about REQUIRED_NEW, but when this is a new transactional, if the external transaction fails, it will not fail all.

Thanks !!

Paulo

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Catalog updateCatalog(CatalogPrice catalog, Long id) {

    CatalogEntity catalogEntity = CatalogEntity.findSingle(id);

    Catalog catalog = catalogHand.updateCatalogPrice(catalog);

    catalogEntity.sendToQueue(catalog);

    return catalog;
}
```

Comment: In what way do you need to use the persisted entity? Can you share a code snippet or a more detailed use case?

Comment: Well some code would really be useful. My guess is that it is not the problem of a transaction (all calls are inside the same transaction so newly created objects should be visible) but of your persistence provider that did not flush operations to DB. Try to flush manually and see if it helps.

Comment: Sorry, i put an example of code, it really helps.

Comment: I'm not really sure why your updatePrice method returns PriceService. The update price method body could look something like `return session.merge(price)`, which would return the merged instance which you could then use.

Comment: Sorry, bad example...but the problem is, when i update the price, the database is not updated, and when i send to the queue, exists another listener that take the id from the queue and sends the update price to another system. but when i send the price to the queue, the listener is more fast and take the price not updated...

Comment: Sending the message to the queue (I'm assuming it's a JMS queue) should be done in the same, global, XA transaction. Or you should wait for the transaction to complete before sending the message to the queue (but then the sending could rollback without rollbacking the original transaction, which may or may not be a problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the same transaction boundary - any changes you made (CREATE or UPDATE) will be visible. I believe you need to call flush() method between the method calls.

```
// Create code 
entityManager.flush(); // If you use JPA, or it will be session.flush() for hibernate
// Update code goes here
```

Persistence context is flushed only when you call flush() explicitly or when you search for the entity or when the transaction commits. Only in these cases the changes you made will be available.